# Can't connect using ssh to Kali Linux

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, debian, kali-linux

Sorry for my English...

I to try to connect  my Debian Computer to Kali Linux Computer with SSH, without success ... can connect my Kali Linux to Debian Computer, but not the opposite...

I to build on `.ssh/config` on my debian Computer

> Host name_host_debian
>
> User username

and  on Kali Linux  `.ssh/config` File

> Host name_host_kali
>
> User username

When write on my Debian `sudo ssh root@192.xxx.xxx.xxx`
asked for Kali Password, I give it, but every Time asked for it,

> Permission denied, please try again.

With service ssh status, to come these Window,

[Window from ssh status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTQCO.png)

Can Please someone help me with these Problem, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, ssh does not allow root user access and must be enabled manually using:

```
sudo sed -i 's/#PermitRootLogin prohibit-password/PermitRootLogin yes/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
sudo service ssh restart
```

source: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-ssh-secure-shell-service-on-kali-linux

Comment: Thanks for your answer!, I to write your command on my debian, but nothing to change...

Comment: you need to write the commands on Kali machine, not on Debian machine

Comment: You need to apply the change to the server side (kali) course, not the debian client.

Comment: @Danfossi and EOhn , very Thanks, I to update my ssh on Kali, service ssh restart  and NOW to come it... Veryyy Thanks ! I wisch your a nice Weekend!